# How to decode date and get date in correct format in ajax success?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, date, asp.net-ajax

Hello Friends I am getting not error but some issue in getting date in ajax success so tell me how can i correct this

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {},
            url: "edit-registration.aspx/GetUserInfo",
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                var objData = eval("(" + data.d + ")");
                var rows = objData.Table1.length - 1;

                $("#disabilityCertIssueDate").val(objData.Table1[0][15]);
             },
            error: function (e, v) {
                alert('there is some error');
            }
        });
```

Data are return in json from abc.aspx.cs page

```
public static string DataSetToJSON(DataSet ds)
{
    try
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
        {
            object[] arr = new object[dt.Rows.Count + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;
            }

            dict.Add(dt.TableName, arr);
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return json.Serialize(dict);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.Message;
    }
}
```

I am getting correct date format on cs page but in success i am getting /Date(787170600000)/ this so how can i retrieve in correct format and set to html5 date control

Answer (score 0):

Format date before passing to JS as string - It would be valid value for html5 input.

Example:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM");
```

[javascript date specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: But i am getting date in that formate in success /Date(787170600000)/. So how can i get in (YYYY-dd-mm)

Comment: you getting `/Date(787170600000)/` on the **client side**, format your date **before** you pass them to client: int this statement: `arr[i] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;`

Comment: yes i am getting this because i am passing date like above format so what should i do ... to recover it